# How Configure Jboss-eap-6.1 to external ip access in port https(8443)

Tags: http, https, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I want to put my jboss to be accessed by the https port from an external ip. For the http port it worked but for the https port does not work.
My standalone.xml jboss:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

And the connector:

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
     <ssl name="https" key-alias="jeve_key" password="jevepass" certificate-key-file="/opt/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/configuration/jeve.keystore" verify-client="false"/>
</connector>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was the proxy that was preventing access to the https of a external ip. I removed the proxy and it worked